# Why can't one of my Rpis talk to bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth

I have a [Tilt hydrometer](https://tilthydrometer.com/) for homebrewing. I've been using this [python script](https://github.com/atlefren/pytilt) to talk to it from one of my Rpi 3B+ devices (running Raspbian stretch).  I have a second device and am trying to mimic the behavior.

This was easy to setup in the beginning.  There is some software to add and a `setcap` command to run.  Here is the `getcap` result:

> root@raspi:/# getcap -rv /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7 = cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+eip

I've verified Bluetooth is enabled by toggling the setting on the desktop and verified that there is an error generated when it is turned off. I get no such error when I run the pytilt.py

I ran btmon on both devices and on the one that doesn't work I get no device activity. Just this:

```
pi@raspi:~ $ sudo btmon
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.43
= Note: Linux version 4.14.58v7-aufs (armv7l)                                                                  0.652734
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                                                                       0.652744
= New Index: B8:27:EB:32:21:2D (Primary,UART,hci0)                                                      [hci0] 0.652747
= Open Index: B8:27:EB:32:21:2D                                                                         [hci0] 0.652749
= Index Info: B8:27:EB:32:21:2D (Broadcom Corporation)                                                  [hci0] 0.652752
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.14                                                     {0x0001} 0.652756
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.14                                                          {0x0002} 0.652982
```

On a whim, I ran the pytilt script while btmon was running.  The last line looks important:

```
        Scanning: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                            [hci0] 98.524896
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Command Disallowed (0x0c)
```

The script throws no error, but it never reports data.  It's as if it just doesn't see the device.  but I can verify that the other pi can see the device at the same time.

is it possible access to the device is blocked by a firewall rule or other security setting? Could some other process have access blocked? Something else to check?

Comment: if the two RPi are the same model, then switch the SD cards

Comment: I've never heard of firewalls for bluetooth, and there definitely aren't any "bluetooth firewalls" enabled by default on raspbian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I researched this I stumbled upon this [discussion](https://ukbaz.github.io/howto/beacon_scan_cmd_line.html) of bluetoothctl.  I was walking through it and after issuing the command `set-scan-filter-clear` and `scan on`, I started seeing devices.
Not sure how a filter might have been entered.